# How to avoid exceptions when querying in Titan?

Tags: exception, titan, nosql

I'm new to Titan. Sometimes I get 
"getcom.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanException: Could not execute operation due to backend exception"
OR
"com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: Permanent failure in storage backend"
when executing a query command especially the number of edges is more than one million. But it does not always happen.
Does anybody know how to avoid it?

Comment: The exception message tells you that it is an exception in the storage backend. So you should look in the log file of your backend, like *cassandra.log* when you are using Cassandra for example. In general a complete stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, we are using cassandra. We tried to look the log. It showed two kinds of mesages, such as "cassandra dead but subsys locked" and 
"cassandra dead but pid file exists". It seems the backend has already crashed... So we want to avoid this awful situation...